# Ajax : passing value to json by special method

Tags: json, ajax, node.js

I am developing a application which depends on nodeJS, and I found that I can't pass value to the JSON in standard way like below

```
$(".test").each(function(i, e) {
                var testID = $(e).html();
                $(testID).click(function(){

                    var postData = {};
                    postData.profileId = "120";
                    postData.region = "1";
                    postData.postUrl ="www.google.com";

                    var api_submit = "/buzz/view/data/editRegion"; //API
                    $.post(api_submit, postData).done(function (data) {

                        });
                    });
                });
```

It didn't gave out any error message but the JSON didn't update at all.
Am i doing this wrong in nodeJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following `Ajax` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: api_submit,
    data: JSON.stringify({ profileId: 1, region: 'xx', postUrl: 'xo' }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // You must specific this!
    dataType: "json", // This is the returned data you'll get, if it's not json there will be an error
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

If your node app is accepting `json`, then this ajax function will work.

### Edit:

Alternatively you could create the object `before` the `ajax` function

```
var postData = {
    profileId: "120",
    region: "1",
    postUrl: "www.google.com",
};
```

Then simply change the following line from:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ profileId: 1, region: 'xx', postUrl: 'xo' }),
```

To:

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

Comment: i tried it, but it seem doesn't send anything to the json

Comment: What do you mean by `i tried it, but it seem doesn't send anything to the json`. Im not sure what you're using on your node server? Are you using express.js? If so make sure you use the bodyparser package on npm!

Comment: sorry, you are right, it's the problem from the back-end , thanks, i solved it

Comment: @anson920520 - Great!